# Recursive listing of a particular file type in Windows PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-7, wildcard

I was trying to recursively list using `ls` all the `*.py` files in a directory in Windows PowerShell. It didn't work. I checked up on the `man` page and then [online page](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849800.aspx) that `-Recurse` flag doesn't accept wildcards so `*.py` wouldn't work.

I want to know whether there is a simple in-built way to recursively list the files of a particular file extension in a directory using Windows PowerShell 2.0?

I am a newbie in PowerShell and don't want to indulge in Shell scripting at this stage. So please recommend in-built commands, flags, etc. only, if any.

By commands I means the in-built keywords of the PowerShell. I am not sure if that is proper vocabulary for PowerShell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the Filter parameter:

```
ls $path -filter *.py -recurse
```

Answer (score 3):

This will do the trick for you.

```
gci -Recurse | ? {$_.name -match ".py"}
```

or

```
gci -Recurse -Include *.py
```

Answer (score 0):

ls is an alias for Get-ChildItem. (So is dir and gci). A simple Google will give you all kinds of examples but the thing to know is -include (or -exclude) are built in parameters that will show (or not show) file types you are looking for. An additional parameter, -filter, can also be used for partial file types. The switch parameter -recurse checks the contents of subfolders in the directory as well. Example01:
gci -path \$computername\$directory -Include *.py -recurse 
Example02: 
gci -path \$computername\$directory -Filter *.*py* -recurse

I like to suppress errors so a full example would look like this:
gci -path \Svr01\C$ -Include *.py -recurse -erroraction SilentlyContinue

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how anybody would have got this working at any time.

gci -recurse works fine and lists all
gci -filter *.txt works fine, lists all .txt files but does not recurse

gci -filter *.txt -recurse returns either only .txt files from root or nothing.
It seems to apply the *.txt filter to the directory names therefor seeing no directories and thus does not recurse at all.